# Renew Apple Developer Program with different email address

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I am thinking to renew Apple Developer Program with a different Apple ID. Reason: There is a big mess in my iTunesConnect dashboard. I have started a lot of app, but not yet approved, and I do not want to continue them, or just created to claim for the app name. So it is hard to delete them. And CloudKit Dashboard is also messy. There is plenty of container I have to scroll a lot to find the appropriate one.

I thought I remove all my apps from App Store, and I will resubmit with my new developer program from new account.

Do you know any drawback?

Comment: Have you tried [contacting Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) to ask them to remove the old apps and entries?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve any of your apps, contact Apple developer support directly before you do anything. They have telephone support as well as web support and have been very helpful in helping me (and several of my clients) in situations exactly like you describe.

For us, if time deadline was pressing due to business needs - we simply paid for a new account and got to work until the deadline passed and then support personnel assisted us with transferring assets and/or crediting us with extra time since we had renewed earlier than normal.

It's usually far simpler to just fix the issues with the problematic account.

Comment: both of the issues are only annoying details, too much info until I understaned how they works, because they are not question of life and death apple doea not really help, tries only via support form .. but it is time to renew my account so fortunatelly I can start with a new and clean page :-)